# How to uniformly distribute pics on a curve?

Tags: diagrams, foreach, tikz-pic, tikz-path, bezier

I want to create a path in the form of a Bezier curve and place pic figures evenly along the path.
In this example, the pics are only placed between the last two points of my curve and they are not evenly distributed, the spaces are not the same between each pic.
How to do ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.pic={\draw[fill=cyan!10]circle[radius=10pt];}]
\draw[help lines](0,0)grid(16,6);
\draw(1,1)..controls(1,5)and(5,5)..(6,3)..controls(7,1)and(15,2)..(14,5)
foreach \t in {0,0.125,...,1}{
    pic[pos=\t]{cc}
};
```

\end{tikzpicture}[image]

Comment: If you want an evenly distribution across the length of a curve (or a whole path) use the [`markings`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.markings). Pics, nodes and coordinates will get distributed evenly across the time of a path segment (line, curve, etc).

Answer (score 5):

The TikZ algorithm that places coordinates, nodes and pics on a line or curve [explicitly](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.8) or [implicitly](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.9) does so according to a “timer” and on a per-path-segment basis, meaning

```
\path (a) -- pic {cc} (b) -- pic {cc} (c);
```

places a pic halfway between `(a)` and `(b)` one pic halfway between `(b)` and `(c)`.
For straight lines the time corresponds to the fractional distance between the start and endpoints, for curves this is the [*t* variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

For placing elements distrubted evenly across the distance of a path (or subpath), the `markings` decoration of the [`decoration.markings` library](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.markings) has to be used (unless you want to do the math yourselves).

It provides the `mark = at position pos with code` syntax where *pos* can both a unitless fraction or a distance as well as the `mark = between positions start pos and end pos step stepping with code` syntax.

Both are used in the code below. Since TeX arithmetics aren't very precise, the position `1` will need manual adjustment so that it is actually placed (stepping of 0.1249 or position 0.999).

I'm using an ellipse to show that the marking is rotated along the path.

---

For applying two different kinds of markings, it's adviced to move the decoration settings inside the `postaction`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.pic={\draw[fill=cyan!10]circle[radius=10pt];}]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (16,6);
\draw (1,1) .. controls (1,5) and ( 5,5) .. ( 6,3)
            .. controls (7,1) and (15,2) .. (14,5)
  [
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      name=markings,
      mark={
        between positions 0 and 1 step .1249 with
%        \pic {cc};
        \draw[fill=cyan!10] circle[y radius=5pt, x radius=10pt];
      }
    }
  ]
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  CC/.style={
    decoration={
      name=markings,
      mark={
        at position #1 with
        \draw[fill=cyan!10] circle[y radius=5pt, x radius=10pt];
      }
    }
  }]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (16,6);
\draw (1,1) .. controls (1,5) and ( 5,5) .. ( 6,3)
            .. controls (7,1) and (15,2) .. (14,5)
  [
    postaction=decorate,
    CC/.list={0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, .999}
  ]
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  CC/.style 2 args={
    decorate, % moved inside here
    /utils/temp/.style={
      decoration={
        name=markings,
        mark={at position ##1 with \draw[fill=#1]circle[radius=10pt];}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#2}},
  CP/.style={CC={pink!25}{#1}},
  CB/.style={CC={blue!25}{#1}},
]
\draw[help lines](0,0)grid(16,6);
\draw[% decoration styles moved inside the postaction
  postaction={CP={0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.999}},
  postaction={CB={0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8}}
]  (1,1) .. controls (1,5) and ( 5,5) .. ( 6,3)
         .. controls (7,1) and (15,2) .. (14,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: For the last picture, you could of course create a style that allows `/.list={pink/0.1, blue/0.2, blue/0.3, pink/0.5, …}` but I think separating this makes it easier to not have to repeat colors/styles with the downside that we have to decorate the path twice.